# How to Show Only Few Categories in Header in Porto Theme in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: header, porto-theme, porto

I have a lot of categories on my store. I want to show just few categories in header here so that the header looks shorter. You can see in the screenshot the header has occupied 60% of the page space.

I am using Porto theme in Magento 2.4.3

[image: Home Page Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable from Back-end(admin panel).

> Go to Catalog->categories->Edit Category->Disable "Include in menu".

Clean cache may require indexing.[image]